# Is there a way to put a anchor component in an context menu in vaadin 14?

Tags: java, anchor, contextmenu, vaadin14, vaadin-grid

Im trying to get a vaadin anchor component inside of an context menu, but I cant get it to work.
I tried it like following:

```
this.contextMenu.add(anchorFile);
```

But the menu item inside of the context menu wont appear.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the text content for your `Anchor` component?

The proper way to add the Anchor as menu item is this.

```
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(targetComponent);
    Anchor vaadin = new Anchor("https://vaadin.com/","Vaadin");
    menu.addItem(vaadin);
```

`add` methods also adds the component to the menu, but wont't wrap as menu item. It is more purposed for adding decorative components like dividers etc.

```
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(targetComponent);
    Anchor vaadin = new Anchor("https://vaadin.com/","Vaadin");
    menu.add(vaadin);
```

Moreover with `addIten` method you can set the event listener for menu item being selected:

```
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(targetComponent);
    Anchor vaadin = new Anchor("https://vaadin.com/","Vaadin");
    menu.addItem(vaadin, event -> {
        System.out.println("Selected");
    });
```

Comment: I tried it like you said with addItem, but with that a blank menu item appears (also when I set the text for the anchor) and the anchor doesn't get called on click.

Comment: The problem appears because of the dynamic creation of the anchor, so I will accept your answer. Thanks for helping!